# my table td span text is not adding and removing in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in which I have 2 tr . Inside it there are td in first td . there is services name . When I select the checkbox of one row then then I want the first td text in an input but and when I select the second checkbox I want the second tr td first value in that input , And if I want to insert both tr td first value I am inserting it , but when I untick on checked checkbox then both the td first values or removing in input,  I want I f I untick one checkbox then It should remove first tr td text from Input and I when I untick second checkbox then It romoves its tr td text . here is my code , hope you understand

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Service </th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th scope="col">tax</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class='servicetr'>
                    <td class="service">
                        <span>Subscription Charges</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>500.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="service">
                        <span >90.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='servicetr'>
                    <td>
                        <span>registration fees</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>200.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <span >80.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00"  /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="services" id="services" style="width:100%;">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){  
                if (this.checked){  
                    var servicetext = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(0).find('span').text();
                    var totalamt = $('#services').val();
                    if(totalamt != ''){
                        $('#services').val(totalamt + ", " + servicetext); 
                    } else {
                        $('#services').val(servicetext);
                    }
                }
                if(!this.checked) {
                    var servicetext = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(0).find('span').text();
                    $('#services').val('');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("change",".tot_amount",function(){  
    var servicetext = [];
    $(this).closest('table').find('.servicetr').each(function(idx, elem) {
        if ($(elem).find('td:last input').is(':checked')) {
            servicetext.push($(elem).find('td:first span').text());
        }
    })

    $('#services').val(servicetext.join(', '));
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2s5Lz3v6/